# GA different results on segment conditions

Tags: google-analytics

why ga:sessions metric give me different values

when using segment conditions:

```
sessions::condition::!ga:PagePath==/
```

as compared with

```
sessions::condition::ga:PagePath!=/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first example will return only sessions that didn't pass through the root (/) page.
The second example will return sessions that pass through at least one page that is different from the root page.

Notice that in the second segment the root page CAN be included in the sessions, it just need to have more visited pages.